# Long freeze on WebRTC iOS native SDK

Tags: ios, webrtc, simplewebrtc, webrtc-android, webrtc-ios

I am working on an iOS app that uses WebRTC's native SDK to provide access to streams from different cameras. The codec used is H264/AVC.

Although most camera streams work perfectly fine, there are some that consistently freeze when the streams are first launched. It looks like the frames are not being decoded but I am not sure how to go about fixing it.

When I enable debug logging, I see a lot of the following in WebRTC's logs:

> (rtp_frame_reference_finder.cc:240): Generic frame with packet range [21170, 21170] has no GoP, dropping frame.
> (rtp_frame_reference_finder.cc:240): Generic frame with packet range [21169, 21169] has no GoP, dropping frame.
> (video_receive_stream.cc:699): No decodable frame in 200 ms, requesting keyframe.
> (video_receive_stream.cc:699): No decodable frame in 200 ms, requesting keyframe.

When there is a freeze, **VideoBroadcaster::OnFrame** on **video_broadcaster.cc** is never called which prevents the entire stream flow from starting. When I test on Xcode and pause/unpause the debugger, almost always the stream will starting working and I see **VideoBroadcaster::OnFrame** getting fired and frames start being decoded. So somehow the pause/unpause process fixes the issue and kicks off the stream.

On the iOS SDK that the encoders are never setup. I have used the **RTCVideoEncoderFactoryH264** encoder provided by the SDK. I have provided implementations for the interface/protocol **RTCVideoEncoderFactory** and also tried overriding the encoders in the SDK. In all of these cases, the **createEncoder()** function is never called. There are no issues with the decoder however, it sets up correctly.

In the **RTCInboundRTPVideoStream** stats report, **PLICount** and **NACKCount** are steadily increasing. My understanding is that the receiver is letting the other peer know there is picture loss in the encoded video.

Since I don't know what exactly is preventing the frames from being decoded, I would like to restart to the stream when I PLICount or NACKCount increasing.

How can I do that without going through the whole SDP offer/answer process? The only way I see is to toggle the **isEnabled** flag on **RTCMediaStreamTrack** but that doesn't fix the problem for me.

Are there any encoding/decoding parameters I can update to restart the stream?
What could be the reason for pausing/unpausing the debugger fixing the issue?

Comment: Are you responding to PLI RTCP feedback?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how can I respond to the increasing PLI count, I am not sure how I can do that through the iOS SDK. I am fairly new to WebRTC, I was thinking I need to send a FIR on seeing the PLI count go up. Is my understanding correct?

If it helps, here are offer and answer SDP:

[Offer](https://pastebin.com/jCmkju6R)

[Answer](https://pastebin.com/EF0EPR90)